# how to to run a script and get a result in boolean in shell script

Tags: shell, deployment, jboss

I needs to run a CLI script to deploy a application and I should save the output of the script as a boolean variable to know whether the deployment is successful or not ?

Can you please help me to do the above scenario :

This is my CLI script :

/applic/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=localhost:9999 --commands="deploy /applic/jboss/Project/deploy/sample.ear --force, deployment-info --name=sample.ear, quit"

It will give an output like below :

NAME       RUNTIME-NAME  PERSISTENT ENABLED STATUS
sample.ear sample.ear      true       true    OK

So, I needs to run a script which should give me the output like, whether my deployment is successful or not ?

I have created one shell script to do that. But, no luck.

#!/bin/bash

AA="[ -e /applic/jboss/Project/script/new_deploy.sh ]"
if `$AA`
then
    echo "deployment successful"
else
    echo "deployment unsuccessful"
fi
echo "done"

Can anyone let me know, how to modify the script to display the output?

Answer (score 0):

Does /applic/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/jboss-cli.sh exit with a non-zero status if the deployment somehow fails? That would be the easiest method:

```
if /applic/jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=localhost:9999 --commands="deploy /applic/jboss/Project/deploy/sample.ear --force, deployment-info --name=sample.ear, quit"
then
    echo deployment succeeded
else
    echo deployment failed
fi
```

If you have to parse the output to determine the level of success, then things get a bit thornier. But answer the first question first.

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks. It works. But, how to grab the CLI scripts output into a separate file ?

Comment: What does "grab the CLI scripts" mean?